# Apache Default page instead of Laravel Application

Tags: apache2, php, 21.04, webserver, laravel

I am sure this is the kind of question that is annoying, but I am brand new to ubuntu and I am totally lost, hence I don't know what to google for.

I have to deploy a laravel application on a Ubuntu 21.04 VM, I connect via SSH & a VPN to the VM (its from my university).

I installed the laravel application successfully and when I run `php artisan serve` it works, I get the message `PHP 7.4.16 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started`

However, when I then enter the IP of the server in my browser I get the default apache webpage, when I enter the IP with port 8000 I get that the server is not responding.

I tried googling but I just don't know what to google for, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running `php artisan serve`, that command is starting its own webserver. And based on the output you posted, it is listening only on `127.0.0.1:8000`.

So accessing it outside of that machine is not allowed. [Based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460833/how-to-set-a-domain-name-with-php-artisan-serve) on Stack Overflow, you can override the default host with the `--host` parameter.

In your case you can run it like so:

```
php artisan serve --host=<IP_ADDRESS_OF_THE_VM>
```

or you can make it open to the world with

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Sadly the outcome or rather the things I see when visiting the site are the same :/

Comment: @newbie When you run the command, is the output changing from `http://127.0.0.1:8000` to the host you are setting?

Comment: Yes that works! I get this PHP 7.4.16 Development Server (http://132.231.36.101:8000) started - but I still have that the server is not responding

Comment: I tried some more stuff and when I try to run your command now I get error message that it "Failed to listen on <IP_Address> + a port - reason: Cannot assign requested address

Comment: @newbie does it work when you use `0.0.0.0` in the command? Do you have any firewall enabled?

Comment: gotta try that! I am not sure since I didn't set up the server. It is from my university and I need to have the vpn running to access it, so it is just available inside the university network

Comment: I just tried wit `0.0.0.0`but it doesn't work either. I am so fucked

Comment: I don't know that the issue in the end was, but I just wiped everything, tried it again and then your solution worked! Thanks a lot :)